# Leer datos de base de datos ACCESS 2010 usando OPENROWSET

Tags: sql, sql-server

Primero que todo voy a decirles mi escenario: Windows Server 2012 R2 64, ACCESS 2010 32, SQL SERVER 2008 R2 64 ejecutando con la cuenta de Administrador, AccessDatabaseEngine 32. Lo que necesito hacer es conectar el sql a la bbdd access. He probado primero creando un servidor vinculado y despues usando OPENDATASOURCE y OPENROWSET y en los 3 casos obtengo el error
"El proveedor OLE DB 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' no puede usarse para consultas distribuidas porque está configurado para ejecutarse en el modo de subprocesamiento controlado simple."
He buscado bastante en internet y unido todas las soluciones y he seguido todos los pasos que adjunto al final y sigo con el mismo error, además me he conectado mediante SSMS con la cuenta de Administrador y también con sa y siempre el mismo error. Como cosa curiosa y extraña es que despues de instalar el AccessDatabaseEngine "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB" no me aparece en los proveedores en Objetos de servidor.

Muchas gracias y saludos.

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'AllowInProcess', 1
EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'DynamicParameters', 1
exec sp_configure 'Advanced', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO
exec sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO
exec sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1
GO

EXEC sp_addlinkedserver   
   @server = N'DATOS',   
   @provider = N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',   
   @srvproduct = N'OLE DB Provider for ACE',  
   @datasrc = N'C:\SERVIDOR\DATOS\BBDDs.accdb';  
GO


SELECT id From OpenRowset('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',';Database=C:\SERVIDOR\DATOS\BBDDs.accdb;','SELECT * from Productos') as B
GO

SELECT *  FROM OPENDATASOURCE('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Data Source=C:\SERVIDOR\DATOS\BBDDs.accdb')...Productos
GO
```

Comment: Te puede ayudar esto: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nlX-F8p09Gc  ???

Comment: Si no te aparecen los objetos como proveedor significa que SQL Server en teoria no los esta reconociendo. Ya trataste utilizando una version de 64 Bits del Access? Ya que la instala reinicia de preferencia todo el server o al menos el servicio, Creo que la razon es que estas usando la version de 32 bits y todo lo demas es de 64.